# Should a parent CSS class be added to the markup or @extended?

Tags: coding-style, html, css, inheritance, code-reuse

Reading [SASS basic features](http://sass-lang.com/guide) on their website, I stumbled upon the `@extend` feature.

The example they give is the following:

```
.message {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
}

.success {
    @extend .message;
    border-color: green;
}

.error {
    @extend .message;
    border-color: red;
}

.warning {
    @extend .message;
    border-color: yellow;
}
```

That compiles to

```
.message, .success, .error, .warning {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
}

.success {
    border-color: green;
}

.error {
    border-color: red;
}

.warning {
    border-color: yellow;
}
```

Thus with this snippet of HTML

```
<div class="success">hello world</div>
```

you style your element with properties of `.message` and `.success`. However I feel this way of writing HTML (and CSS) very poor, in terms of semantic (you don't explicitly see from the markup above that the element has *also* the styling of `.message`).

Shouldn't the snippet above be

```
<div class="message success">hello world</div>
```

?

I feel it to be more descriptive, and more easily reusable. For example I could assign the `.success` class (as written in the above CSS but without the `@extend`) to other elements which are not messages, and so using the class as a modifier, in a BEM-fashion.

**So my question is, is the SASS example approach more desiderable than mine?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both approaches are valuable and semantically, they are not very different. Remember that you also can use both in Sass.

I believe that what makes you think that yours is more descriptive is their choice of class names: `success` class is not descriptive enough: how would anyone guess that `success` refers to a message, and not, say, a small green check icon on the side of an item showing whether a unit test passed? If we chose a (meaningless) example with better names, things become clearer:

```
.animal { ... }
.cat { @extend .animal; ... }
.dog { @extend .animal; ... }
```

Would you rather write:

```
<div class="animal cat">...</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="cat">...</div>
```

Probably the second variant, since it avoids redundancy and makes your HTML more readable.

If you know object oriented programming, think of:

- Their approach as inheritance: `Cat` class inherits `Animal`, and can have only zero or one base classes.
- Your approach as interfaces: `ISuccessful` interface can be implemented by both `Message` class and `TestResult`; at the same time, `Message` can implement at the same time `ISuccessful`, `IImportant` and `IMandatory`.

Comment: Yes, there are cases where the "single class" approach isn't worse, or is even better as the one you reported, but in CSS I saw more often the other case, hence my question.

Comment: I see only now your edit, that's a very good point. But isn't the interface approach more broadly used as it permits to add functionalities more easily? (I'm actually quite ignorant in this field, so I'm not really trying to protect my position)

Comment: @mattecapu: from my experience, your approach is used indeed more frequently in CSS.

Comment: @mattecapu It's probably more frequent because it's more flexible.  With the "clearer" animal-based example, if you have interactivity with javascript, you'll either have to select all types of animals or go back and add the `animal` class to the elements.  It also distinguishes between ambiguities in English - for example, is it "[bat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat)" or "[bat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball_bat)"?

Comment: @Izkata yes these are other benefits of that kind of approach, I didn't think about it

Answer (score -1):

Coming back a year later, I now support the exactly opposite view: `@extend` is *usually* better than filling your markup with classes.

Let's take for example this code

```
.component1 {
   font-family: 'custom font', sans-serif;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   border: 2px dashed red;
}
.component2 {
   font-family: 'custom font', sans-serif;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
}

<div class="component1"></div>
<div class="component2"></div>
```

I notice `component1` and `component2` share a common style, that could potentially be used in other components as well: it's a good candidate for a separate class (by the DRY principle),

```
.utility1 {
   font-family: 'custom font', sans-serif;
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
.component1 {
   border: 2px dashed red;
}
.component2 {
   padding: 10px;
}


<div class="component1 utility1"></div>
<div class="component2 utility1"></div>
```

But this code brings at least 2 new problems in town:

1. If I'm coding sensically, `component1` and `component2` styles will live in different stylesheets. This means that by looking at `component1.css`, I can see all the styles that are going to be applied to the component, except this is not the case anymore: `utility1`, which will probably reside is a separate stylesheet, changes the styles of the component *without any explicit reference to it in the component own stylesheet*.
   Another way to see this is that you are not tying the `utility1` styles to `component1`, but you leave them as separate entities that could as well live separately, yet this is a false assumption because `component1` needs *always* those styles, and can't live without (it's not a state like a modifier class, it's part of its very own visual *nature*).
2. Even worse, this reference *is moved into the markup*.
   In the question, I talk about semantics, but while in the case of a modifier class (i.e. `--active`, `--hidden`, `--warning/--error/--success`), an extra class in the markup *will* actually provide additional semantic information on the component, it isn't the case here. **`utility1` is a purely styling hook**, and styling has no place in the page markup except for stylesheets declarations in the `<head>` section. Putting `utility1` in the component markup is no different from styling things from the `style` attribute. **You're relying on markup code to change the visual styles of your components, and that's no good**.

I understand these views are not absolutely shared or right (there is not such a thing as an absolute truth in coding, yet we can agree on some general principles), because there are school of thought that sees [styling from markup as completely legit](http://acss.io).

Comment: why the downvote?